# ASP.NET Core program.cs configuration

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

I am converting code to a .net core application. In my original application, I have the following code in my `startup.cs`:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
                      WebHostEnvironment env,
                      ApplicationDbContext dataContext,
                      ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
                      IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
                      IHostApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
{
    ConfigureSeriLog(httpContextAccessor);
    loggerFactory.AddSerilog();
    app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
}
```

I need to bring this configuration into the `program.cs` of my new application.  Since `program.cs` does not have a `Configure` method, how do I gain access to `httpContextAccessor` so I can pass it to `ConfigureSerilog`?

Comment: Why does your `Configure` method have so many dependencies? And you _should not_ be injecting your EF `ApplicationDbContext` because it's meant to be a short-lived object.

Comment: So the real question is how to integrate Serilog with Microsoft.Extensions.Logging? There's a package for that, [Serilog.Extensions.Logging](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging)

Answer (score 0):

In your program you can do this to get access to that.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();
```

You can do everything you need with the two items above like you use to in older version.

Here is link to do most other examples as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: I have those in my program.cs already.  When I try to reference ConfigureSerilog(httpContextAccessor), VS underlines httpContextAccessor with a red line.  The error states 'the name httpContextAccessor does not exist in the current context'.